# xfs_fsr reports insufficient freespace on large VM images

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, xfs, fragmentation, defrag

I have several systems using glusterfs and xfs partitions. Some of these systems are hosts for VMs (using libvirt and with qcow2 for storage).

I noticed that there was some substantial fragmentation in several cases so I ran xfs_fsr to defrag. Two of my VMs are rather large and I receive an "insufficient freespace" when attempting to defrag the partitions they are hosted on.

Is there a way around this? I'm not sure I understand the -f option, is that what I should use?

EDIT: I took out a related question that I will ask in a different post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xfs_fsr` defragments a file by *copying* it to a new temporary location and atomically swap the new (contiguous) file with the old one. This obviously means that it *really* need sufficient space to make the temporary copy (ie: at least as much free space as the file you are defragmenting).

From [`xfs_fsr` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_fsr):

> xfs_fsr improves the layout of extents for each file by copying the
>   entire file to a temporary location and then interchanging the data
>   extents of the target and temporary files in an atomic manner. **This
>   method requires that enough free disk space be available to copy any
>   given file and that the space be less fragmented than the original
>   file.** It also requires the owner of the file to have enough remaining
>   filespace quota to do the copy on systems running quotas. xfs_fsr
>   generates a warning message if space is not sufficient to improve the
>   target file.

Its `-f` option enable you to specify the progress file location which, in turn, is used  when restoring an interrupted defrag session. Again, from the man page:

> **-f leftoff**
>
> Use this file instead of /var/tmp/.fsrlast to read the state of where
>   to start and as the file to store the state of where reorganization
>   left off.

Comment: Hi thanks. Am I correct in thinking the free space must also be on the same partition? There is definitely enough space on that system, but on other partitions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: free space must be in the same partition (and filesystem).